# Best way to enforce this data-integrity constraint?

Tags: sql-server, data-integrity

I have 3 tables (lets call them Foo, Bar and Baz.

Tables:

### Foo

- FooId

### Bar

- BarId
- FooId

### Baz

- BazId
- BarId
- AnotherValue

Obviously the foreign keys make it so that each Baz is associated with a Bar, and hence, associated with a Foo.
Now I want to ensure that for each set of Baz with the same "AnotherValue" all the associated Foo's are unique

For instance, if I had

```
Foos (1, 2, 3)
Bars ((10, 1), (11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 2))
Bazs ((100, 10, "a"), (101, 10, "b"), (102, 13, "a"), (104, 11, "b"))
```

this should be blocked because Baz 104 and baz 101 both have AnotherValue "b" and Foo 1.

---

**Options I have thought of** (in order of my current preference)

### Indexed View

I could create a view over these three tables and put a unique index on the two columns

### Computed Column

Add FooId as a computed column to Baz.  Then add an index on AnotherValue and FooId.

### Check Constraints

I'm pretty sure this can be added and will work.  I haven't used check constraints much, and I'm not sure if it is the best way to do this.

### Trigger

This just seems ugly to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but it seems like you want to carry the FooId down to the Baz table and add an Alternate Key (Unique contraint) on FooId,AnotherValue.

```
Baz
•BazId
•BarId
•FooId
•AnotherValue
```

Comment: This would effectively be the view which is indexed.  The "carry down" is handled by the view and then a unique index constraint is applied to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just restating using different names:

```
Parent (ParentID) 
       (1, 2)
Child (ChildID, ParentID) 
       ((10, 1), (11, 1), (13, 2))
GrandChild (GCID, ChildID, GCAndParentVal) 
       ((100, 10, "a"), (101, 10, "b"), (102, 13, "a"), (104, 11, "b"))
```

Could you have that field in another table with the parentID and baz.anotherValue instead of including it in the table with the childID?

like this:

```
Parent (ParentID) 
       (1, 2)
Child (ChildID, ParentID) 
       ((10, 1), (11, 1), (13, 2))
GrandChild (GCID, ChildID, ...) 
       ((100, 10, ...), (101, 10, ...), (102, 13, ...), (104, 11, ...))
AnotherChildValue (ParentID, AnotherVal)
       ((1, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "a"), (1, "b"))
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but no, the Parent ID needs to come from Child.

Comment: This would cause a referential integrity issue between the ParentID on Child and the ParentID on AnotherChildValue.

Comment: Why?  The PK on the AnotherChildValue table would keep your invalid record (1,"b") from being accepted.  The Parent table would have FK relationships with both Child and AnotherChildValue.